# OpenAI GPT-3 API: Why do I get an unexpected response?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-api, gpt-3

I am connecting to the GPT-3 API through a Jupyter Notebook. This is the code:

```
import openai
import os

# Set up your API key
openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]

# Choose the API endpoint
model_engine = "davinci"

# Create a prompt
prompt = "Hello, ChatGPT!"

# a temperature of 0.5 returns gibberish
# Generate a response
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine = model_engine,
    prompt = prompt,
    max_tokens = 1024,
    temperature = 0.5,
    frequency_penalty = 0.5,
    presence_penalty = 0.5
)

# Print the response
print(response.choices[0].text)
```

Attempting to debug the code led to me playing around with the `temperature`, `frequency_penalty` and `presence_penalty`. I figure I'm doing something wrong if I can't make it work with such a simple prompt.

If you want an example of the unexpected responses I am getting from the simple prompt above, here is the beginning of a few of them:

> I’m here to review a product that I was sent for free. This is not a
> paid advertisement and all opinions are my own. I have been using the
> new Bamboo Pen & Touch tablet from Wacom for about a month now and I
> have to say that I am very impressed with this product! The Bamboo is
> a tablet designed for the everyday user, whether you are an artist or
> just someone who likes to sketch on the computer. It’s also great for
> people like me who use their tablets primarily for writing.

> ChatGPT is a chat bot powered by Google Assistant. It can handle up to
> 10,000 messages per month for free and more if you pay for premium
> services. This bot can be used for customer support, sales and
> marketing, human resources, and more. In this tutorial, I will show
> you how to create a chatbot using ChatGPT with PHP. We will use
> Laravel as a backend framework. If you don’t have an account at
> ChatGPT yet, sign up here first.

I was expecting a simple "Hi, how can I assist". What's incorrect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old GPT-3 model (i.e., `davinci`). The performance of the OpenAI API is model-related. Newer models are more capable.

- `text-davinci-003` <-- use this one
- `text-davinci-002`
- `davinci`